# Conectar wordpress mediante ajax usando javascript

Tags: ajax

Alguien en su blog ha usado wordpress y lo ha conectado mediante ajax usando javascript?
Mi pregunta es la siguiente...
Como seria la funcion que me regrese los posts mas vistos en el blog sin usar pluggins y utilizando javascript

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de Wordpress hablas `.org` o `.com`? Si se trata de un dominio propio podrías registrarte en Google Analytics, y usar su información para mostrar los posts más vistos: por día, por hora, por semana, por mes... o como quieras. Yo lo tengo así, sin plugin, mediante la API de Google Analytics, de la cual obtengo la información y la actualizo. [Aquí lo puedes ver](http://www.deiverbum.org), es el widget que aparece abajo, a la derecha. Para el número de visitas de cada página en particular, también, aunque aquí tuve que registrar los datos en una BD la cual actualizo 1vez / día.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress de base no trae un contador de vistas así que tendrás que implementar uno:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Luego para implementar ajax hay un tutorial base aqui:
https://decodecms.com/ajax-en-wordpress-de-manera-correcta/